# Rad Studio xe6/xe7 TMediaPlayer Component no video

Tags: delphi, video

I was playing around with Delphi and tried running the example "MediaPlayedHD" provided by embarcadero. The thing is that when trying to run an mp4 [video](http://techslides.com/demos/sample-videos/small.mp4), it says unsupported format even though it is on the list of files I can open. When again trying to run a .avi file it plays only sound. So I decided to try it myself. I created a simple form with a button a *mediaplayer* component and a *mediaplayercontrol* component. I linked the  *mediaplayercontrol* component to the *mediaplayer* and added an **onButtonClick** event that would simply do this

```
MediaPlayer1.FileName := 'lizard.avi'; //Don't ask if it was in the right directory. it was.
MediaPlayer1.Play;
```

The thing is that if I use ffmpeg as an external command the files play correctly, so what is going on, is this a problem with Delphi, or is it just me not knowing what I'm doing?

Comment: Open the files with windows media player to see if they'll play ok.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz Yes I tried that, as I said I even tried ffmpeg just to see if everything is ok.

Comment: I belive that the problem you are facing is the lack of proper system video codecs. WHy? If I try playing the provided video file ny my standard computer with DivX, Xvid and AC3 codecs installed the video plays just fine in "MediaPlayedHD" sample application. But if I try playing this video on another test machine which doesen't have these video codecs installed I get the "unspuported video" error.

Comment: Also do note that while some codec packs could alow you to play such file in Windows Media Player it doesent necessarily means that you could play such files in other media playing programs. Why? This is becouse some codec packs ara capable of detecting when WMP opens and oad only then but don't load when other media playin programs run. That is why I myself never use codec packs but rather install each codec directly.

Comment: @SilverWarior Ok, but how do I fix this, because the files play normaly with various media players. So shouldnt that mean that I have the codecs, or is there some way I should link them to Rad Studio?

Comment: Which media players do play the files normaly? You see many media players nowadays come with their own video codecs or use some open source coedcs as their internal codecs. Most known example for this is VCL media player. So first you need to find a media player which doesen't have its own codecs to see if those files do play or not. Only then would you be able to see if the problem is in codecs or somewhere else.

Comment: I guess you meant vlc, witch I tried, as well as media player. I will see how to install some video codecs though and report back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is found in the Embarcadero Help for FMX.Media.TMediaPlayer:

*In order to play an audio file using TMediaPlayer, use the appropriate format: 
.wav on Windows 
.caf on iOS and Mac OS X 
.3GP on Android*